# Using custom field within do_shortcode

Tags: php, custom-fields, shortcode, advanced-custom-fields

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong as I don't have too much experience with PHP.

I'm creating a listing for a caravan dealer and they want to show a gallery per caravan. The caravans are created in custom posts with custom fields.

I have a custom field that specifies a Gallery ID from NextGen. I need to pull this in per post to display the assigned gallery to the listing.

Based on what I have read on here I have:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[ngg_images gallery_ids='{$caravan_gallery}' display_type='photocrati-nextgen_basic_thumbnails']");?>
```

caravan_gallery being the custom field and`[ngg_images gallery_ids="ID" display_type="photocrati-nextgen_basic_thumbnails"]` being the shortcode.

Can anyone explain where I am going wrong and how to fix ?

Comment: The shortcode is correct and should work well. Are you sure that `$carravan_gallery` gets the correct value? Try this line: `echo "[ngg_images gallery_ids='{$caravan_gallery}' display_type='photocrati-nextgen_basic_thumbnails']"` and see what it outputs...

Comment: thank you. Now I'm getting a 'no images were found' error so I can only assume this is on the NextGen end and the code is doing what it should? Now to figure out where thats coming from.

Comment: The code is good, just check if your NextGen galleries really exists and have images. Go to the following url: `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=nggallery-manage-gallery`.

Comment: The gallery exists and is showing when the shortcode is added directly to a page [link](http://stcs.amplifymediasolutions.com.au/about/) but not in the template [link](http://stcs.amplifymediasolutions.com.au/caravan/millard-sunseeka-pop-top-17-x-78/)

Comment: I can't access the links. So, I think the problem is with the  `$carravan_gallery`. Try echoing it and paste here the output.

Comment: It outputs the number 1 which is the gallery id.

Comment: Sorry, I ran out of ideas about this...

Comment: Thank you so much so far, at least I know it should work. I'm guessing it is a NextGen issue. You've been a huge help!